# Initialization after class declaration C++

Tags: c++

In the following constructor I'd like to initialize the `_register` bitset along with `POLY`. Is it possible to initialize more than one bitset after the colon? Is there another way to initialize a bitset in a constructor?

```
private:
    std::string message;        
    const std::bitset<4> POLY; 
    std::bitset<4> _register;  

public:
    CRC4(std::string message); // constructor declared 

// constructor defined
CRC4::CRC4(std::string message) : POLY (std::string("0011")) // initialize POLY 
{
    this->message.assign(message); // initialize message 
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: you have forgotten one closing paren at the `POLY` initializer.

Comment: and yes, you can add any number of initializers, separated with commas (See @DanielFrey's answer)

Comment: I also found I can set each bit one at a time within the constructor definition. But I cannot make a call to the bitset constructor within my constructor.

Comment: All member variables are constructed in the initialization list (or default constructed) before the body (starting with `{`) of your constructor is executed. This is especially important for member variables marked `const`: You can *only* initialize them in the initializer list, not the body as at that time, they are already constants there.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any number of intializations to the initializer list, separated by comma:

```
CRC4::CRC4(std::string message)
  : message( message ), // initialize message
    POLY (std::string("0011")), // initialize POLY
    _register(std::string("0011")) 
{
}
```